# $.ajax() .then() isn't being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to execute the remote code completion example in Jquery Mobile using the following url: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/

I use latest PhoneGap with jquery mobile version 1.4.3

the auto complete javascript code:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#drink_brand_autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
                var $ul = $( this ),
                        $input = $( data.input ),
                        value = $input.val(),
                        html = "";
                $ul.html( "" );
                if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                    $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://myalcoholist.com/drink-management/drink/drink-brand-autocomplete",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: {
                            q: $input.val()
                        }
                    })
                            .then( function ( response ) {
                                console.log("response");
                                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                                });
                                console.log(html);
                                $ul.html( html );
                                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                            });
                }
            });

    });
```

in chrome developer console i can see that the ajax call is being executed fine and the server returns a json array.

the .then() is not being executed, no ideas why.
i tried .done() instead but i got the same results.
i don't get any javascript errors.

any ideas?

Comment: does remote API support jsonp? As an FYI ... `crossDomain: true` is useless to an actual cross domain call

Comment: That URL returns a full web page starting with <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 when querying this page you get a proper json response. for example http://myalcoholist.com/drink-management/drink/drink-brand-autocomplete?q=mon

Comment: @ufk, you're so right, my bad. (OT: I had a bottle of Monin in my drinks cabinet for many years - didn't like it, though the bottle was very attractive).

Comment: changing jsonp to json solves it.